# Why is the windows return code called HRESULT?

Tags: c, windows, hresult

The standard return type for functions in Windows C/C++ APIs is called `HRESULT`.

What does the H mean?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a programming problem.

Comment: @numerodix: As I know HRESULT type is standard type for OLE\COM, not for whole win32. Also this question is total off-topic.

Comment: If SO is an Question/Answer site to for an extended FAQ of programming code issues, I'd think that the foundation terms of coding should be included. Or should this be a question posted to programmers exchange?

Comment: It is System Hungarian for "handle".  First paragraph in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679692%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: This is not off-topic.  A question does not have to be about a **problem**, it can be a general question.  And this question involves a data type used in programing, so it is relavant.

Comment: Microsoft uses the H prefix everywhere - HRESULT, HWND, HINSTANCE but it doesn't always have the same meaning.  It depends on the API.

Comment: FWIW, I was looking for an answer to this question, and this page is where I found it, so thanks.

Answer (score 11):

**Result handle** as stated [here at MSDN Error Handling in COM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679692(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 5):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb446131.aspx) only says:

> The return value of COM functions and methods is an **HRESULT**, which is not a handle to an object, but is a 32-bit value with several fields encoded in a single 32-bit ULONG variable.

Which seems to indicate that it stands for "handle", but is misused in this case.

Answer (score 4):

The `H`-prefix in [Windows data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types) generally designates handle types<sup>1</sup> (such as `HBRUSH` or `HWND`). The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/error-handling-in-com) seems to be in agreement, sort of:

> The `HRESULT` (for *result handle*) is a way of returning success, warning, and error values. **`HRESULT`s are really not handles to anything**; they are only values with several fields encoded in the value.

In other words: Result handles are really not handles to anything. Clearly, things cannot possibly have been *designed* to be this confusing. There must be something else going on here.

Luckily, historian Raymond Chen is incessantly [conserving](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/) this kind of knowledge. In the entry aptly titled [Why does `HRESULT` begin with H when it’s not a handle to anything?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180117-00/?p=97815) he writes:

> As I understand it, in the old days it really was a handle to an object that contained rich error information. For example, if the error was a cascade error, it had a link to the previous error. From the result handle, you could extract the full history of the error, from its origination, through all the functions that propagated or transformed it, until it finally reached you.

The document concludes with the following:

> The COM team decided that the cost/benefit simply wasn’t worth it, so the `HRESULT` turned into a simple number. But the name stuck.

In summary: `HRESULT` values **used to be** handle types, but aren't handle types any more. The entire information is now [encoded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/structure-of-com-error-codes) in the value itself.

---

**Bonus reading:**

Handle types losing their reference semantics over time is not without precedent. [What is the difference between HINSTANCE and HMODULE?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040614-00/?p=38903) covers another prominent example.

---

<sup>1</sup> *Handle types store values where the actual value isn't meaningful by itself; it serves as a reference to other data that's private to the implementation.*

Answer (score 3):

Hex Result.

HRESULT are listed in the form of 0x80070005. They are a number that gets returned by COM\OLE calls to indicate various types of SUCCESS or FAILURE. The code itself is comprised of a bit field structure for those that want to delve into the details.

Details of the bit field structure can be found [here at Microsoft Dev Center's topic Structure of COM Error Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690088(v=vs.85).aspx) and [here at MSDN HRESULT Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231198.aspx).